# FirebaseMessagingService subscribe only for selected type of user login

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push) blog to add the capability to get push notification work with my Xamarin app and Azure push notifications.

But the issue I have is that my app is used by 2 kinds of users, one needs push notifications and other don't. Is there a way I can prevent the app from registering from notification by default when it launches.

Think of users like `Supervisors` and `Employees`, wherein `Supervisors`need the ability to  be notified whereas `Employees` don't.

I have also tried to unregister from the FCM using the following code, ***_which is a bad idea*** I am told in many of the blogs, but even that is not working and it crashes.

```
public async void EnableNotifications(bool status)
{

    if(status)
     {
         Firebase.Iid.FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.GetInstanceId().AddOnSuccessListener(this);
     }
     else
     {
         Task.Run(() =>
         {
             try
             {
                 Firebase.Iid.FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.DeleteInstanceId();
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 iLogger.Error("LocationService", ex.Message);
             }
         }).Wait();
         //Firebase.Iid.FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.DeleteToken(Firebase.Iid.FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token, INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);
     }

}
```

you may ask why do you bother to unregister, I see that the Azure push notifications has a limit on `Active devices per namespace   500`

so my question is how can I selectively subscribe based on the type of user login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution, thought of sharing here in case someone is in same state as me.

Idea is to actually disconnect from the `Azure NotificationHub` instead of trying to disconnect from `Firebase Cloud Messaging`.

so on my `MyFirebaseMessagingService` class ended up modifyng the `OnNewToken` as below.

```
private static NotificationHub hub;
public async override void OnNewToken(string token)
{
    Log.Debug(TAG, "FCM token: " + token);
    // save the token for later use to register with the notification hub.
    await SecureStorage.SetAsync("fmc_token", token);  
}
```

now created two static functions to register and unregister from the notification Hub on this `[service]` class.

```
public static async Task RegisterForNotifications(Context context)
{
    // get the token received with the previous step
    var token = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("fmc_token");
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
    {
        var dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .SetNegativeButton("Close", (sender, args) =>
         {
            // User pressed Close.
        })
         .SetMessage("Registration Token is not available to receive notifications. This could be an installation issue, please uninstall and reinstall the application and retry. If it still do not work, please contact support for help.")
         .SetTitle("Registration Error!")
         .Show();
    }
    else
    {
        if (hub == null)
        {
            hub = new NotificationHub(Constants.NotificationHubName, Constants.NotificationHubListenConnectionString, context);
        }
        // run this on a separate thread else we get an exception at runtime.
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var deviceId = await GetDeviceId();
            var tags = new List<string>() { deviceId };
            var registration = hub.Register(token, tags.ToArray());
            var regID = registration.RegistrationId;
            await SecureStorage.SetAsync("hub_registration_id", regID);
            Log.Debug(TAG, $"Successful registration of ID {regID}");
        });
    }

}
public static async Task UnRegisterForNotifications(Context context)
{
    var localHub = hub;
    if(localHub == null)
    {
        localHub = new NotificationHub(Constants.NotificationHubName, Constants.NotificationHubListenConnectionString, context);
    }
    // run this on a separate thread else we get an exception at runtime.
    await Task.Run(() => {
        localHub.Unregister();
    });
}
```

now after the user login, depending on the need I can selectively call the above function to register / unregistered for the server push notifications.

```
if( loginUser.Category == "Manager") {
MyFirebaseMessagingService.RegisterForNotifications(this);
}
```

during logout I can simply call

```
MyFirebaseMessagingService.UnRegisterForNotifications(this);
```

Hope  this helps!